# Bahij TheSansArabic-Bold not working in Crystal Reports PDF

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report using "Bahij TheSansArabic-Bold" for text, for english text it is working fine on designer and on generate to PDF, but the arabic working on designer and not working when exporting to PDF.

i tried to added it in the registry and in fonts still the same.

am using crystal report v13.0.12, and visual studio 2015, framework 4.5.
windows server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pdf exports, Crystal requires that the font has embedding permissions.
See: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1214944